# Approval Pull Request Pending Notification after X time delay

Tags: notifications, azure-devops, pull-request

On Azure Devops i need to create a Pull request notification which alert my team by email or Teams notification if the pull request is pending for more than 1 hour.

What i ve already tried is to go on 
Project Settings ---> Notification ---> Add Subscription

But i m not finding any particular reference to filter or setting which i can use for my purpose.
Does anyone have an idea on how to implement it?
[New notification subscription azure devops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pall9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that this feature does not available currently.

While using new subscription in the notification setting, you can only get the notification when the pr is created. Until now, Azure Devops does not provide this feature which can help you achieve get notification after the pr is pending for more than 1 hour.

If you want this feature for your better work, you can raise your feature demand [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to promote development of richer features.

Note: After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously